# Allow a contact to view cases across multiple accounts Dynamics 365 Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

I'm working with a Customer Self-service Portal instance in Dynamics 365 and have the possibility of a contact(user) being linked to one or more accounts via a Many-to-Many relationship. I'm trying to find a way to change the out-of-the-box Case entity list to show cases for any account the contact is linked to with this new relationship but so far haven't found anything that will work.  I have considered just replacing the entity list view with some custom fetchxml in Liquid code, but I'm thinking the entity permissions for Case would have to be global then, instead of Contact or Account scope?  I'm looking for a way to make this work with entity permission at Contact or Account scope.

I tried changing the account entity permission to use the new Many-to-Many relationship I created so that the current contact/user should be able to access all the accounts they are associated with, but I'm missing how to get to the next step of  then showing all cases for those accounts.

Any suggestions?  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found the missing piece to make this work.  Once I had the entity permission to the account entity (let's call it Account of Contact) using the new Many-to-Many relationship (contact to account), I then created another entity permission record for the Case entity with a scope of Parent and selected the "Account of Contact" permission as the parent, and picked the existing incident_customer_account relationship.  Once this was parented, I was able to go to the out-of-box support home page and view all cases for accounts my contact was associated with via the Many-to-Many relationship.